# Azure blob storage deployment: ERROR: Please run 'az account set' to select active account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

Trying to deploy new commit to blob storage, and this suddenly happened even the changes in the commit are minor (some styling stuff).. anyone idea how to solve it?

```
Run azure/CLI@v1
  with:
    azcliversion: 2.0.72
    inlineScript: az storage blob upload-batch --source ./build --destination '$web' --account-name "xxxxx"
  
  env:
    NODE_VERSION: 10.x
    STORAGE_ACCOUNT: "xxxxx"
    AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT: 
    AZUREPS_HOST_ENVIRONMENT: 
Starting script execution via docker image mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli:2.0.72
ERROR: Please run 'az account set' to select active account.
Error: Error: az cli script failed.
cleaning up container...
MICROSOFT_AZURE_CLI_1637163117325_CONTAINER

(node:1734) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: az cli script failed.
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/azure/CLI/v1/dist/index.js:1:23964
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/home/runner/work/_actions/azure/CLI/v1/dist/index.js:1:20436)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:1734) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1734) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is the reponse of command az account list, I have only one account
[image]

Here is the code of fiel main.yml which is used for automatic deployments on github.

```
name: CI

on:
    push:
        branches: [ master ]
    pull_request:
        branches: [ master ]

env:
  NODE_VERSION: '10.x'
  STORAGE_ACCOUNT: 'xxxx'
  SUBSCRIPTIONID: 'yyyyyyy'

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
    - name: npm install and build
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build --if-present

    - uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
    - name: Upload to the storage account
      uses: azure/CLI@v1
      with:
        azcliversion: 2.0.72
        inlineScript: |
            az storage blob upload-batch --source ./build --destination '$web' --account-name ${{ env.STORAGE_ACCOUNT }} --subscription ${{ env.SUBSCRIPTIONID}}
    - name: logout
      run: |
            az logout
```

Comment: You can list your subscriptions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_account_list

And you can set one of them active:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_account_set

Comment: I have only one account in the list and it's enabled

Comment: @HardRock it can be selected as default in your local environment but not inside the container

Answer (score 0):

az cli cannot find a resource in you current default subscription

Maybe your Storage Account name is wrong, or this resource was removed

If there is another subscriptions or your container does not have any reference to *az cli* profile (*~/.azure*), you have 2 options to resolve it:

1. Each script run set the default subscription

```
az account set --subscription <subscription-id>
```

2. Add `--subscription` parameter to each *az cli* command, if you are working with different subscriptions

```
az storage blob upload-batch --source ./build --destination '$web' --account-name "xxxxx" --subscription <subscription-id>
```

Comment: I added --subscripiton <my subsvription id> but still same error and same issue..
Storage name is correct, all previous deployments were successful and then this error came suddenly.. I updated question with az account list and main.yml file
Any help is appreciated

Comment: @HardRock, could you try another version ?  `azure/CLI@v1.0.4` for task and `azcliversion: 2.29.2`

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. It seems that there is issuse with github and azure cli versions... in the end I just changed ` azcliversion: 2.30.0`
Here is to read more https://github.com/Azure/cli/issues/56